# TinyMCE move caret after inserting span

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, caret

I am creating a TinyMCE plugin with custom button that insert `<span>test</span>` in current caret position. Moreover clicking this button again while caret is in previously inserted text is removing current `<span>test</span>` and replacing it with new inserted `<span>test</span>`.

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('test_plugin', function(editor) {
   editor.addButton('test-button', {
      text: 'Insert span',
      onclick: function() {
         var current_node = editor.selection.getNode();

         if(current_node.tagName === 'SPAN') {
            current_node.remove();
         }

         editor.insertContent('<span>test</span>');
      }
   });
});
```

It works great but after inserting `<span>test</span>` the caret get stuck in this span node and I can't move it outside of this span.

Adding `&#32;` (whitespace) at the end (`<span>test</span>&#32;`) solves the problem of stucking caret but it is adding redundant spaces every reinsert.

**How to solve stucking caret problem?**

OR

**How to remove redundant `&#32;` when reinserting?**

Comment: This question was the answer I was looking for (:D), your code works at my end (tinyMCE 5.x.x). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, sounds wierd.
You could try to reset the caret after inserting the span. This might help.

Insert the span in this form `<span id="my_new_span">test</span>`.

```
var my_span = ed.getBody().querySelector('#my_new_span');
ed.selection.select(my_span);
ed.selection.getRng(1).collapse(0);

// remove the id attribute
my_span.removeAttribute("id");
```